# Извлечь содержимое с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace

есть строка вида

```
'[text1] text2 - text3'
```

или

```
'text2 - text3'
```

то есть иногда есть `[text1]` в квадратных скобках, а иногда нет,
и всегда перед `text2`  есть `-`

нужно что бы средствами php обрезало и оставилоcь только `'text2'`

пример:

```
[Гайд] For Honor - Завоеватель - непоколебимый защитник
Overwatch - Глава Xbox прокомментировал ситуацию с использованием мыши и клавиатуры 
World of Warcraft - В игре началась “Любовная лихорадка”
```

должно получится

```
For Honor
Overwatch
World of Warcraft
```

Comment: Пример данных дайте. Что в `test\d` может быть?

Comment: А какое регулярное выражение получилось у вас?

Comment: добавил примеры

Comment: В `text2` может быть ` -`?

Comment: нет нет нет нет

Comment: неужели такое сложное задание

Comment: Что значит `неужели такое сложное`? Здесь, как правило, не дают готовых решений, а помогают разобраться в вашем. Где то, что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: Покажите то, что вы уже написали. А мы подправим.Для удобства можете испольщовать один из онлайн конструкторов регулырных варажений. Ну... Или делать всё через implode \ explode с массивами и разными условиями.

Comment: А ещё, автор, отмечайте пожалуйста ответы на вопросы как принятые, если они вам помогли (слева от ответа галочка). Этот вопрос постарайтесь дополнить - добавьте регулярку, которая у вас получилась, даже если она совсем нерабочая, тогда минусы к вопросу постепенно превратятся в плюсы.

Comment: та с удовольствием, никто ж не помог

Comment: у меня проблема с регулярными выражениями... не могу даже с конструктором сделать, не понимаю я в них

Comment: Да ну бросьте вы, какие знания - какие деньги, нужно то...  мышечная память, вы же говорили - несложно

Comment: @NickolayS попробуйте пройти любой курс по регулярным выражениям или документацию по PHP почитать. Они сложные, но понять-то можно.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого подойдёт вот такое просто регулярное выражение:

```
(?:\[.+?\])?\ ?(.+?)\ \-\ .+
```

Рабочий пример: https://regex101.com/r/p6oW3g/3